# Undefined index:jawaban

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, loops

I want to input multiple data to database using array, but I got an error message. The code are in the following bellow :

ClusterController

```
$jawaban = $request->jawaban;

$data = [];
if($jawaban != null || $jawaban == false){
  for($i=1; $i<=count($jawaban['jawaban']); $i++){
     $data[] = array('jawaban' => $jawaban[$i]['jawaban']);
  }

  $store = Soal::where('cluster_id', $id)->update($data);
  return dd($store);
}
```

showexam.blade.php

```
    <form action="/jawaban/store/{{$model[$i]->id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    @csrf
        <table id="datatable" style="width:100%">
        <tbody>           
            <tr>{{$i+1}}. </tr>
            <tr>{{$model[$i]->soal}}</tr>
            <ol type="A" style="">
                <li> {{$model[$i]->A}}</li>
                <li> {{$model[$i]->B}}</li>
                <li> {{$model[$i]->C}}</li>
                <li> {{$model[$i]->D}}</li>
                <li> {{$model[$i]->E}}</li>
            </ol>
            <input list="browsers" name="jawaban[]">
            <datalist id="browsers">
              <option value="A">
              <option value="B">
              <option value="C">
              <option value="D">
              <option value="E">
            </datalist>
        @endfor
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-right" id="modal-btn-save">Done</button>
    </form>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what do you get if you dd($request->file('jawaban')) in your controller??

Comment: I don't see any use of an index named `string` :S. Where does it say the error is coming from?

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace.

Comment: Side thought: I thought PHP arrays were 0 indexed?  Why not `$i = 0;` I think the issue (if not another) is with how you are iterating that array, show us what the output of `$jawaban` is please.

Comment: Why `$jawaban['jawaban']` ?

Comment: `$jawaban = $request->jawaban; dd($jawaban);` what does this give you?
I think you should `count($jawaban)`. I don't think you are dealing with associative arrays here.

Comment: @MatthewBrown Yes, PHP is zero-indexed. You're right, `<= count()` should give IndexOutOfBounds-problems. But the error happens as part of evaluating `count($jawaban['jawaban'])` which doesn't change during the loop.

Comment: Show us the contents of $jawaban please

Answer (score 0):

`count($jawaban['jawaban'])`

You already have an array called jabawan that you retrieved with  `$jawaban = $request->jawaban;`

That jabawan will have a normal counting array `$jabawan = ['A', 'B']`

It will not have an index called jabawan.

If you had done something like

`$jabawan = post();`

You could use your code, but you can just use

```
for($i=0; $i<count($jawaban); $i++){
   $data[] = array('jawaban' => $jawaban[$i]);
}
```

Change `Soal::where('cluster_id', $id)->update($data);`

into

```
if ($soal_model = Soal::find( $id )) {
   $soal_model->update($data);
}
```

The problem is that you're never calling `get()` on the query object, or a `first()` on the collection that the `get()` returns.

By using `find()` You get an object back or null if it doesn't exist.
By wrapping that in an if statement the update will only be executed on an existing object, preventing errors on trying to update a null value.

Also, you cannot return a `dd()`.

dd stands for 'dump and die' I believe, at least that is what I read into it because that's what it does.

It dumps the data and then kills the process. So all laravel return handlers won't get called after your `dd()` call. You killed the process.

Comment: hi, I tried your advice and and then a new error comes. it says Undefined offset: 15, what should i do?

Comment: @tasyadas does it give the same error at the same line? Or in a different part of the code?

Comment: the same line,  precisely in row  $data[] = array('jawaban' => $jawaban[$i]);

Comment: holy guacamoly. I never checked your for loop how you built it up... An array always starts with 0. Never at 1. I fixed it my code. `for($i=0; $i<count($jawaban['jawaban']); $i++){` Also never check if the counter is lesser than or equal to the length of the array. check if it's less than the length of the array. I suggest reading up on https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/arrays/

Comment: it works! :) @Tschallacka but there is no data entered into database

Comment: @tasyadas thats probaly because your data format doesnt correspond to your model. Since you didnt post your model details, I'd recommend to add public $jsonable = ['jawaban']; if your jawaban field is a text field. But without knowing model layout I can't help further